# How to redirect users from personal landing page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

When users login to Office 365 `http://portal.office.com/`, they land on their "SITES" page `https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxx_company_com/Social/Sites.aspx` by default.

How to change this so that users are redirected to a page in one of the collections?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a script to redirect the user:

```
function onLoadActions(){
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("onLoadActions");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you tell me where should I keep this code? I am not able to find any page called "Sites.aspx" in sharepoint designer. Also not able to figure out which master page is this page using.

Comment: You can put the script in a script editor or content editor webpart.  Are you able to navigate to the page in question?  If so can you use the gear at the top right of the page to see an edit page option.  Then insert the webpart using the ribbon bar.

Comment: If I edit the page, I am getting the warning "You are editing the Personal Version of this page". I want this change for all users.

Comment: I work on a non-office 365 version of SharePoint, but it sounds likely you'll need to put the script in the masterpage for it to apply to all pages like that.  If you did put it in the master you would need to have a way to make sure the redirect doesn't trigger on all pages though.  We'd likely want to check the url of the page to make sure its redirecting when you want it to.

Comment: I can check for (window.location.href.indexOf("/Social/Sites.aspx") > 0) but the problem is I cant figure out where to keep this piece code.

Comment: You'll have to find which masterpage is being used by the site.  if you can get into SharePoint Designer you should be able to go to the masterpages and find the one that has the "make default" grayed out; that one should be the current master.

Comment: Also, try going to Design Manager from the site gear icon. Then on the "Publish and Apply Design" option there's a link "Assign master pages to your site based on device channel".  The default master might be listed in the top dropdown menu.